# Converter class getAsObject pass parameter to Service class which accepts object

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, converters

I have question regarding Converter class `getAsObject` method

I have a service called `EmployeeService employeeService`

```
public List<Employees> getEmployees(Employees employees);
```

If I want to call the above method from getAsObject of Converter class which as arguments

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component,
            String value)
    employeeService.getEmployees(<?>)
```

How do I pass `employees` object to `getEmployees` method from `getAsObject`?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Update 1

```
@Entity
public class Employees implements Serializable {

private String employeeNumber;
private String employeeName;
```

Comment: The task is unclear. What is an `Employees` class, a typo, or a class with `List<Employee>`? What are you converting and to what: `Employee` based on `id`, `Department`, `List<Department`, something else?

Comment: @skuntsel There was a typo in my post, I have corrected. I want to get employees based on employeeNumber.

Comment: And what is `Employees` class?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? If not, specify your requirements more explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a following converter, that simply converts number (which is a `String`, according to your code) to `Employee` object:

```
@Named("employeeConverter")
public class EmployeeConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeByNumber(value);//or if it is not a String, replace value with Integer.parseInt(value)
        if(employee == null) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Employee with number: " + value + " not found."));
        }
        return employee;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof Employee) || (value == null)) {
            return null;
        }
        return ((Employee)value).getEmployeeNumber();
    }

}
```

and use it in your views by `converter="#{employeeConverter}"`.

Comment: Like I have mentioned method parameter is of type `Employees' `getEmployees(Employees employees)' so I have to pass employees object, not String

Comment: But the [`Converter` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) provides only for a method that uses the signature `public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value);`. The value is a `String` object. Nothing to do about it. You then convert this string into an object by your service class instance, like in the answer. Maybe you need *another* service that would accept the (already converted from string) object into something else?

Comment: @Polppan you *want* to pass an `Employee` object but **you can't**. As skuntsel says, you can only send a `String` in the `getAsObject` function that contains info to access to the `Employee` info.