# JSF getting object from the selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, object, converters, selectonemenu

I have a problem again with JSF. I am still learning and your help is much apreciated.

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{productBean.productName}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.pizza}" var="pizza" itemValue="#{pizza}" itemLabel="#{pizza.name}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{productBean.valueChanged(pizza)}" render="pizzaResult" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value ="Dodaj do zamówienia"/>
    <h:outputText id="pizzaResult" value="#{productBean.message}" />
</h:form>
```

I just want to call the metod valueChanged with the parameter of custom object: Product. This is the method:

```
public void valueChanged(Product prod)
{
    if(prod.getIs_available() == 1)
        message = "yes";
    else
        message = "no";
}
```

I want it to verify if the product is available. And print it in an outputText tag. I think the problem is in HTML because all data reqested are Strings, and I cannot send an Product in such way. Should I use a converter? How it should look like? I don't know much about converters and the working example of ProductConverter will clear my mind.
THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of the `listener` attribute:

> signature must match public void processAjaxBehavior(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException

So you need to change your `valueChanged` method like this:

```
public void valueChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev)
{
    if(this.getIs_available() == 1)
        message = "yes";
    else
        message = "no";
}
```

However a cleaner approach would be to use a custom [`Validator`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/).

Comment: but I need to pass the value to the method

Comment: when the listener is invoked you can get the value directly from the bean, as it already has been updated

Comment: but my property is "nested" in ArrayList<Product> and the right product has the property. I need to iterate to find the right product on the list anyway

Answer (score 0):

(I still have a question. Please read)
I think I was able to resolve it myself like this: (products is an arraylist with products. Every product has field like name or is_available got from the database in the constructor of the productBean. I iterated through the list looking for the right name and then checked if its available. if not i set right message)

```
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{productBean.productName}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.drink}" var="drink" itemValue="#{drink.name}" itemLabel="#{drink.name}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{productBean.valueChanged(productBean.productName)}" render="drinkResult" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

public void valueChanged(String name)
{ 
    Iterator<Product> ie = products.iterator();
    while(ie.hasNext()) 
    {
        Product actualProd = ie.next();
        String prodName =actualProd.getName();
        int available =actualProd.getIs_available();
        if(prodName.equals(name) && available == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(prodName + available);
            message = " No rpoduct in store, sorry";
            break;
        }
        else
            message = "";
    }
}
```

But i am not sure it is the right way to do such things. What you think?
I want to learn to write web application in Java EE as they should be written. "Ok it works" - it's not enough for me.

Comment: As you've said yourself - you need a converter here. See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/) for a tutorial. You basically need to fit the logic you have here in a `getAsObject` method. The only problem would occur if you have duplicate product names - if this is the case it's better to use a product id for the `itemValue`.

Comment: Yep, the names ar only temporary because i didn't create a field for id yet in the bean

Comment: You don't need a method that takes a parameter here, as your `productName` already *is* a property of `productBean`, that has been set by JSF, and thus available within standard method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass an additional parameter in your listener, as the converted and validated value will be there in your bean. So, you can call you method *on that object directly*. What you need is to implement [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) and bind `<h:selectOneMenu>`'s `value` to your model class.

So, assuming your `pizza` is of type `Pizza` your setup will be the following.

The view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{productBean.product}" converter="#{pizzaConverter}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.pizza}" var="pizza" itemValue="#{pizza}" itemLabel="#{pizza.name}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{productBean.valueChanged}" render="pizzaResult" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value ="Dodaj do zamówienia"/>
    <h:outputText id="pizzaResult" value="#{productBean.message}" />
</h:form>
```

The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProductBean implements Serializable {
    private Pizza product;//getter+setter
    private String message;//getter
    public void valueChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe) {
        message = ((product == null) || product.isAvailable()) ? "" : "Product temporarily unavailable";
    }
}
```

And you need to have a converter properly implemented. Example by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15021966/1820286), there are also numerous examples regarding converter usage on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "And you need to have a converter properly implemented." that's the tricky part for me.

Comment: You don't need to follow that workaround approach. It is both not nice and resource consuming. You *should* know how to implement the converter.

Comment: Pointed you at one example. It is really easy as you understand what's converter all about :)